# P4 sync issue-File not getting deleted

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I have a  workspace with set of files.But i observed that when i delete a file from perforce and do "p4 sync".The file is getting not deleted from the workspace.
But p4 sync -f deletes the file.

Answer (score 2):

`p4 sync` will only delete a file from the workspace if:

1. the head revision of the depot file is deleted  (check `p4 files FILE`)
2. you are currently synced to a different (not deleted) revision of the file  (check `p4 have FILE`)
3. you do not currently have the file open (check `p4 opened FILE`)

The only one of these conditions that is affected by the `-f` flag is #2, so I suspect you had the file in your workspace but weren't on record as having synced it from the server (e.g. the file was put there outside of Perforce, or there was a `sync -k`, or something like that).